# Create a matrix with sequencial values padded with zeros (without loops)

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices `a`and `b` of 1 column and *n* rows.

These matrices represent min and max values.

From these I need to create a *n* by *m* matrix.
*m* is the max value of `[a ; b]`

The result must contain each value between `a(:)` and `b(:)`, padded with zeros.

note: it's easy to do with a for loop, but I want to avoid loops.

### Exemple :

Starting with these two matrices :

```
>> a = [3 ; 5 ; 2 ; 7 ; 4]

a =

     3
     5
     2
     7
     4

>> b = [7 ; 7 ; 5 ; 8 ; 4]

b =

     5
     7
     4
     8
     4
```

I want to end with this matrix :

```
result =

     3     4     5     6     7     0     0     0
     5     6     7     0     0     0     0     0
     2     3     4     5     0     0     0     0
     7     8     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

### So far I have this :

```
>> result = zeros(size(a,1), max([a ; b]));
>> rows = [1:size(a,1)]

rows =

     1     2     3     4     5

>> index = sub2ind(size(result), rows, b - a + 1)
>> result(index) = b

result =

     0     0     0     0     7     0     0     0
     0     0     7     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     5     0     0     0     0
     0     8     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

>> result(:,1) = a

result =

     3     0     0     0     7     0     0     0
     5     0     7     0     0     0     0     0
     2     0     0     5     0     0     0     0
     7     8     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd solve this with a simple loop, which is also probably the fastest solution

```
a = [3 ; 5 ; 2 ; 7 ; 4]
b = [7 ; 7 ; 5 ; 8 ; 4]
nSteps = b-a+1;
nRows = size(a,1);

result = zeros(nRows, max([a ; b]));

for iRow = 1:nRows
   result(iRow,1:nSteps(iRow)) = a(iRow):b(iRow);
end

result =

 3     4     5     6     7     0     0     0
 5     6     7     0     0     0     0     0
 2     3     4     5     0     0     0     0
 7     8     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

In case you don't need readability, here's a non-loop solution:

```
result = ones(nRows, max([a ; b]));
result(:,1) = a;
result = cumsum(result,2);
result(bsxfun(@gt,result,b))=0

result =

     3     4     5     6     7     0     0     0
     5     6     7     0     0     0     0     0
     2     3     4     5     0     0     0     0
     7     8     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: It's usually not recommended to use loops in matlab. I was expecting a no-loop solution.

Comment: The advice to avoid loops is based on evidence that vectorised operations are faster than their equivalent loops.  The evidence for this in the most recent editions of Matlab is much weaker than it was in older editions.  Loop-based solutions have, often, two other advantages over their vector-based equivalents: they can be easier to understand (come back to your favourite cryptic one-liners 6 months after you wrote it), and they can be developed much more quickly.  How many loop iterations could you have run while waiting for a vectorised solution ?

Comment: @Johnny5: I've added a non-loop solution.

Comment: @Mark : we have chosen matlab over c# for a part of our software because we need high performance. If we start coding with loops in matlab, I think we better do it in c# no?

Comment: @Johnny5: If performance is critical, then dogmatically avoiding loops is risky. The JIT can make some loops faster than a vectorized computation that involves slow functions. Consequently, I suggest profiling both options (in fact, you should profile everything, it can be quite a surprise to find where you're losing precious time)!

Answer (score 0):

Some problems aren't worth the effort of vectorising:

```
a = [3 ; 5 ; 2 ; 7 ; 4];
b = [7 ; 7 ; 5 ; 8 ; 4];

cols = max(max(a),max(b))
result = zeros(length(a),cols)

for i = 1:length(a)
    A = a(i):b(i)
    result(i,:) = padarray(A, [0 cols-length(A)], 0, 'post');
end
```